# Cloning Opportunities Not Calculating Expected Revenue

Tags: apex, opportunity, clone

I have an issue where upon cloning opportunities are not calculating expected revenue from original records on a sporadic basis.

There seems to be little commonality in the errors outside of expected revenue always failing to calculate on opportunities within a specific pipeline.

Expected revenue calculates on some opportunities but not on others, regardless of record type. Only one specific pipeline consistently fails to calculate the opportunity.

Main questions here: 
Can report type influence the behavior of Expected Revenue in any way?

We’ve identified a workflow rule that may be the culprit, but it isn’t designed to fire conditionally upon specific records, just on probability field updates.

Has anyone identified an error like this or are there links out there that might better clarify this behavior?

Not seeing much on the boards regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected Revenue is purely the product of the probability and the amount of the Opportunity. As such, nothing can influence the value of ER aside from adjusting those two factors.

Even if you're using forecasting, the ER won't change in an override; it will just be shown differently in forecasting reports.

It sounds like your workflow rule that fires on probability field updates could be an effect, but likely is not the cause. The cause is the actual change in the probability.

The likelihood of ER "not calculating" is almost impossible, but the chances that it is not giving the result you expect, based on what you think the probability and amount are, are much higher.

For some history: Expected Revenue is a standard formula field from a long time ago, before custom formulas were created.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will say that the probability does change, as in we'll start out with 100% Probability on a fully closed opportunity with Amount at 1000. After the clone - the stage is triggered to automatically go down to 30% Probability with Amount at $1000, Probability at 30% and Expected Revenue at $1000, with it should be $300. No idea.